# SSL not working for checkout

Tags: plugins, ssl

i configured an ssl certificate (geotrust through namecheap) for apache on amazon ec2 following instructions at http://splittingelectrons.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/how-to-configure-an-ssl-certificate-for-apache-on-amazon-ec2/ , but then when i try to access the checkout page (the only page that's set up to have https), the page simply says "This webpage is not available" (we are using woocommerce). the rest of the site navigates fine, it's just when i try to go to the checkout page that nothing is loading.

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you force https in woocommerce it doesn't always stick, try running [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/). It worked for me with solving https problems in WordPress and WooCommerce.

Also try [Better WP Security](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) which has security hardening for your WordPress site offers the option to force SSL on certain pages, or whole site. I also highly recommend this plugin.